# How to use cron in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add cron in magento 1.9 . using `config.xml` & observer run cron every 30 minute

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it by adding the followinh code to your config.xml under config like below:

```
<config>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <your_cron>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/30 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>yourmodule/observer::yourFunction</model>
                </run>
            </your_cron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. create your custom module to run cron job. I have explain you how to do this

> create/open your module config.xml file and put below code in

To run a cron job every 30 minute.The fields denote (from left-to-right):Minute, Hour, Day of Month, Month, Day of Week.

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Runcron_Cron>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Runcron_Cron>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Runcron_Cron>
                <class>Runcron_Cron_Model</class>
            </Runcron_Cron>
        </models>   
    </global>           
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <Runcron_Cron>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/30 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>Runcron_Cron/cron::runCron</model>
                </run>
            </Runcron_Cron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

1. create/open your module model file Runcron/Cron/Model/Cron.php And add below code

`class Runcron_Cron_Model_Cron 
{

    public function runCron($observer)
    {

       echo "Run Cron";
    } 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Add code in your config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mycompany_mymodule>
                <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model</class>
            </mycompany_mymodule>                         
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <mycompany_mymodule>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/30 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>mymodule/observer::customFunction</model></run>
            </mycompany_mymodule>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Add this code in your observer :

```
<?php  
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer {  
    public function customFunction() {
        Mage::log('cron working successfully!!',null,'cron.log');
    }  
}
```